# query is not outputting all of the details?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Below is my query:

Found out the problem thanks to Mark Bannister trying MYSQL workbench. It doesn't display one row anymore it displays the rows needed which are below:

```
Course: INFO101 - Bsc Information Communication Technology Year: 3
Student: Mayur Patel (u0867587)

Module: CHI2550 - Modern Database Applications 
Session: AAB 72 (A)

Course: INFO101 - Bsc Information Communication Technology Year: 3
Student: Mayur Patel (u0867587)

Module: CHI2513 - Systems Strategy 
Session: AAD 61 (B)

Course: INFO101 - Bsc Information Communication Technology Year: 3
Student: Mayur Patel (u0867587)

Module: CHI2550 - Modern Database Applications 
Session: AAE 67 (B)
```

So really all I need help on now is how do I display it using php so that it only shows Course details and Student details only once, it will show each module in the course only once and shows each session being below each module it belongs to:

The output from above should look like this in other words:

```
 Course: INFO101 - Bsc Information Communication Technology Year: 3
    Student: Mayur Patel (u0867587)

    Module: CHI2550 - Modern Database Applications 
    Session: AAB 72 (A)
    Session: AAE 67 (B)

    Module: CHI2513 - Systems Strategy 
    Session: AAD 61 (B)
```

PHP code to output the results:

```
$output1 = "";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //$result is the query

    $output1 .= "
          <p><strong>Course:</strong> {$row['CourseId']} - {$row['CourseName']} <strong>Year:</strong> {$row['Year']}<br/>
          <strong>Student:</strong> {$row['StudentForename']} {$row['StudentSurname']} ({$row['StudentUsername']})
          </p>";

    $output1 .= "      
    <p><strong>Module:</strong> {$row['ModuleId']} - {$row['ModuleName']} <br/>
          <strong>Session:</strong> {$row['SessionId']} {$row['Mark']} ({$row['Grade']})
          </p>";
            }

            echo $output1;
```

Thank You

Comment: Can't help you without seeing the PHP that does the outputting. Please edit it into your question.

Comment: @Mayur, have you tried running your query in a SQL query client (such as MySQL workbench) instead of through php? If so, what result do you get?

Comment: Hi, I just have =, I am going to edit the question so you know the results

Comment: Can't really help without seeing the PHP code but it sounds like you will need to do separate sql queries to get all of the data that you require as an inner join will only show where there are matches for each of the tables. A RIGHT JOIN or LEFT JOIN may also work.

Comment: The query looks ok to me. It should output 1 row per session.. Are you taking that into account when you extract the results?

Comment: Mayur, your questions are usually very bad. If you write better questions, you'll get more answers. Here are some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: @MayurPatel, you are abusing the site. You have created at least **five accounts**. You ask the same questions over and over. You have not learned to **[ask better questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)**. You are using us to fix your homework, instead of trying to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have ordered your result-set ascending with sql statement

```
ORDER BY `CourseName` ASC
```

so, the problem is with the first row of your result-set:
Bsc Information Communication Technology Year: 3
The reason is that you already performed something on your result-set.
Go to the first row before the while:

```
//do this before anything:
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
//now, you are at first row
$output1 = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //$result is the query
    $output1 .= "
       <p><strong>Course:</strong> {$row['CourseId']} - {$row['CourseName']} <strong>
       Year:</strong> {$row['Year']}<br/><strong>Student:</strong> 
       {$row['StudentForename']} {$row['StudentSurname']} ({$row['StudentUsername']})
       </p>";
    $output1 .= "      
    <p><strong>Module:</strong> {$row['ModuleId']} - {$row['ModuleName']} <br/>
    <strong>Session:</strong> {$row['SessionId']} {$row['Mark']} ({$row['Grade']})
    </p>";
            }
echo $output1;
```

Ignore my line breaks.